# Laravel Symlink between storage and public is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, server

So I am having issues adjusting from a locally hosted Laravel website to a dedicated server.

I ran this code on Putty to create a symlink. And I think it works as I can see the folder in the Filezilla client.

```
ln -s /home/username/project/storage/app/public/receipts /home/username/public_html/storage/
```

The issue is I cannot access any files stored in the folder. If I cd into the folder in shell i can see all the files there. If I put an image in the public_html/storage folder I can see it by going to website.com/storage/image.jpg but the same image in the app/public/receipts folder does not open when I try website.com/storage/receipts/image.jpg

Also I checked the global configuration for the apache server for allowsymlinks and is checked.

This the first time I've ever tried anything to do with servers so I don't really know what I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

My Php Version is 7.2
Laravel is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo, but the target to your link is `.../public/receipts`. It seems as though you wanted `.../public` instead:

```
ln -s /home/username/project/storage/app/public /home/username/public_html/storage
```

This way, `website.com/storage/image.jpg` would point to `.../app/public/image.jpg` and `website.com/storage/receipts/foo.jpg` would point to `.../app/public/receipts/foo.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't.

Comment: Shucks :/ in that case, can't reproduce this on my end. Did you try checking the owner and permissions on the files? Maybe they aren't accessible to the public?

Comment: I've tried placing an image into the public folder to test I could actually display them, which worked, however I can't achieve this through a symlink. Don't know if this proves the possibility of permissions or not?

Comment: Try running `ls -lR /home/username/public_html/storage` to compare ownership and permissions on the files you placed yourself vs the ones you can't access from the web.